# Vue.js and Canvas: Issue with Coordinate Mapping for Dynamic Dot Layouts

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue & html-canvas try to write a responsive "link Game", here is the sample
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But I found a really strange problem, Because I want to check if the line is "legitimate" when user make a line between two dots.
here is the picture describe what is "legitimate":
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Group1(which is col-1 & col2) may link together.
Group2(which is col-1 & col2) may link together.

To archive this goal, I use a variable to record each dot's information.
`this.Dotlocation[[RowID,ColID,GroupID],[x_location,y_location]]`

But I found that that is whatever I do the information never get correct. here is the result

```
[ 
 // id,col,group
 [ [ 3, 2, 4 ], [ 631.4, 417.43 ] ], 
 [ [ 3, 1, 3 ], [ 495, 417.43 ] ], 
 [ [ 2, 1, 3 ], [ 214, 495 ] ],
 [ [ 1, 1, 3 ], [ 990, 462 ] ],
 [ [ 1, 2, 4 ], [ 631.4, 184.6002 ] ],
 [ [ 1, 1, 3 ], [ 495, 184.6002 ] ],
 [ [ 0, 1, 3 ], [ 990, 171 ] ],
 [ [ 2, 2, 4 ], [ 631.4, 301 ] ],
 [ [ 2, 1, 3 ], [ 495, 301 ] ],
 [ [ 0, 2, 4 ], [ 631.4, 68.2 ] ],
 [ [ 0, 1, 3 ], [ 495, 68.2 ] ],
 [ [ 4, 2, 4 ], [ 631.4, 533.801 ] ],
 [ [ 4, 1, 3 ], [ 495, 533.801 ] ],
 [ [ 1, 1, 3 ], [ 214, 301 ] ],
 [ [ 0, 1, 3 ], [ 214, 107 ] ]
 ]
```

There are several questions in this array:

1. I don't know why id is disordered.
2. The Group&col are incorrect; it seems like the last column's problem

Here is my code ( I'm sorry it's a little bit long):

```
DrawImgOnCanvas(question,context1){
    let Column_Amount=question.length;
    var onchangegroup = false;
    let Column_ID = 1
    this.Group = 1       
    for (let col = 0; col < question.length; col++) { //Column
        console.log("col",col);
        //紀錄錨點資訊
        // let Dot_Row_ID = 1
        const Max_Img_Size = this.CountMaxImgSize(this.QuestionDataStructure[col].length);
        let RWD_Colum_Gap=this.CountRWDYGap(question[col])
        
        console.log(RWD_Colum_Gap);

        for (let Dot_Row_ID = 0; Dot_Row_ID < question[col].length; Dot_Row_ID++) { //Row
            console.log("Group1",this.Group);
            let Img = new Image();
            // let Image_Url=new URL(`../../${question[col][row]}`, import.meta.url).href
            let Image_Url = icon //FIXME: change to dynamic import
            Img.src = Image_Url;

            let Img_Size = this.ResizeRWDImg(Max_Img_Size,Img);
            // Img.height = Img_Size.New_Height;
            // Img.width = Img_Size.New_Width;
            let x = this.Min_border + Max_Img_Size.Max_Width*col + this.RWD_Gap_Width*col
            let y = this.Min_border + RWD_Colum_Gap + Max_Img_Size.Max_Height*Dot_Row_ID
            // let bordr=100
            Img.onload = () => {
                console.log(this.Min_border);
                context1.drawImage(Img, x, y, Img_Size.New_Width, Img_Size.New_Height);
                context1.beginPath();
                if (col == 0) {
                    console.log("Add on Right: Using Group",this.Group);
                    // add on right
                    context1.arc((x+Img_Size.New_Width+this.Min_border), (y+(Img_Size.New_Height/2)), this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID,Column_ID,this.Group],[x+Img_Size.New_Width+this.Min_border, y+Img_Size.New_Height/2]]);
                    context1.fillStyle = 'black';
                    context1.fill();
                }
                else if (col == Column_Amount-1) {
                    // add on left
                    context1.arc(x-this.Min_border,(y+(Img_Size.New_Height/2)), this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID,Column_ID,this.Group],[x-this.Min_border, y+Img_Size.New_Height/2]]);
                    context1.fillStyle = 'black';
                    context1.fill();
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Add on Both: Using Group",this.Group);
                    //Right
                    context1.arc((x+Img_Size.New_Width+this.Min_border), (y+(Img_Size.New_Height/2)), this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID,Column_ID+1,this.Group+1],[x+Img_Size.New_Width+this.Min_border, y+Img_Size.New_Height/2]]);
                    //Left
                    context1.arc(x-this.Min_border,(y+(Img_Size.New_Height/2)), this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID,Column_ID,this.Group],[x-this.Min_border, y+Img_Size.New_Height/2]]);
                    context1.fillStyle = 'black';
                    context1.fill();                
                }
                context1.closePath();
            }
            // Row_ID++;
        }
        if (col != 0) {
            console.log("Change Group");
            this.Group++;
            Column_ID +2 ;
        }
    }
},
```

here is the input datas:

```
question:[  
['assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png'],
['assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png'],  
['assets/GamePic/Cat.png','assets/GamePic/Cat.png']
],

Thank you for your patient, hopes for your reply.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmxjB.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoZX6.png
```

Comment: 1. do you push in ID order? 2. what is incorrect about them?

Comment: ahh, I see, the push is done asynchronously, therefore order is not guaranteed - and `Column_ID +2 ;` does nothing, did you mean `Column_ID += 2 ;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Now I can understand why my ID is disordered, but I still don't know why I can't give correct group and column to each dots. ( P.s I've changed the ```Column_ID += 2 ;```, still not work.) thanks.

Comment: that too is because of asynchrony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the order is not as expected is because loading Images is asynchronous, therefore there is no guarantee that all the code in the `onload` will run in the expected order

Since the code in there also relies on `this.Group` and `Column_ID` and they both can change before the `onload` is called, that explains why the values for `col` and `group` are not as expected

The following uses `async`/`await` to ensure the code runs as expected

There's really only two changes ... marked with

```
// ==========================
```

Also, the `onload` block is no longer indented, but that's not a code change so I didn't mark it as such

```
// ==========================
// make the function "async"
async DrawImgOnCanvas(question, context1) {
    let Column_Amount = question.length;
    var onchangegroup = false;
    let Column_ID = 1;
    this.Group = 1;
    for (let col = 0; col < question.length; col++) {
        const Max_Img_Size = this.CountMaxImgSize(this.QuestionDataStructure[col].length);
        let RWD_Colum_Gap = this.CountRWDYGap(question[col]);
        for (let Dot_Row_ID = 0; Dot_Row_ID < question[col].length; Dot_Row_ID++) {
            let Img = new Image();
            let Image_Url = icon;
            Img.src = Image_Url;
            let Img_Size = this.ResizeRWDImg(Max_Img_Size, Img);
            let x = this.Min_border + Max_Img_Size.Max_Width * col + this.RWD_Gap_Width * col;
            let y = this.Min_border + RWD_Colum_Gap + Max_Img_Size.Max_Height * Dot_Row_ID;

            // ========================================
            // this "pauses" until the image has loaded
            //
            await new Promise((resolve) => (Img.onload = resolve));
            context1.drawImage(Img, x, y, Img_Size.New_Width, Img_Size.New_Height);
            context1.beginPath();
            if (col == 0) {
                context1.arc(x + Img_Size.New_Width + this.Min_border, y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2, this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID, Column_ID, this.Group], [x + Img_Size.New_Width + this.Min_border,y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2]]);
                context1.fillStyle = "black";
                context1.fill();
            } else if (col == Column_Amount - 1) {
                context1.arc(x - this.Min_border, y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2, this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID, Column_ID, this.Group], [x - this.Min_border, y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2]]);
                context1.fillStyle = "black";
                context1.fill();
            } else {
                //Right
                context1.arc(x + Img_Size.New_Width + this.Min_border, y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2, this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID, Column_ID + 1, this.Group + 1], [x + Img_Size.New_Width + this.Min_border,y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2]]);
                //Left
                context1.arc(x - this.Min_border, y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2, this.DotRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                this.DotLocation.push([[Dot_Row_ID, Column_ID, this.Group], [x - this.Min_border, y + Img_Size.New_Height / 2]]);
                context1.fillStyle = "black";
                context1.fill();
            }
            context1.closePath();
        }
        if (col != 0) {
            this.Group++;
            Column_ID += 2;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, this completely solved my question.